# how can i extract another shopping site product for my website?

Tags: xpath

id like to extract prodirectselect.com products for my website and the problem is there are 3 options for sizes ( EU/UK/US ) and i just want EU sizes using Xpath so this is the website source :

```
<option data-uksize="6" data-eusize="39⅓" data-ussize="6½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="6">39⅓</option >
```

so the Xpath is 
//*[@id="size"]

and it just extract the UK sizes and all i need is EU sizes so what should i add to the Xpath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not verry well written (you do not provide the url of the exact webpage for example)

I went to a random shoe entry (http://www.prodirectselect.com/products/Nike-Zoom-All-Out-Flyknit-Black-WhiteCool-GreyVolt-Mens-Shoes-844134002-137750.aspx?)

as I guessed that's an example of the kind of page you were after.

The size section (`//*[@id="size"]`)
is:

```html
<select name="size" id="size" class="medium">
<option value="">Please select a size</option><option data-uksize="6" data-eusize="40" data-ussize="7" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="6">6</option>
<option data-uksize="6½" data-eusize="40½" data-ussize="7½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="6.5">6½</option>
<option data-uksize="7" data-eusize="41" data-ussize="8" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="7">7</option>
<option data-uksize="7½" data-eusize="42" data-ussize="8½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="7.5">7½</option>
<option data-uksize="8" data-eusize="42½" data-ussize="9" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="8">8</option>
<option data-uksize="8½" data-eusize="43" data-ussize="9½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="8.5">8½</option>
<option data-uksize="9" data-eusize="44" data-ussize="10" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="9">9</option>
<option data-uksize="9½" data-eusize="44½" data-ussize="10½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="9.5">9½</option>
<option data-uksize="10" data-eusize="45" data-ussize="11" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="10">10</option>
<option data-uksize="10½" data-eusize="45½" data-ussize="11½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="10.5">10½</option>
<option data-uksize="11" data-eusize="46" data-ussize="12" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="11">11</option>
<option data-uksize="11½" data-eusize="47" data-ussize="12½" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="11.5">11½</option>
<option data-uksize="12" data-eusize="47½" data-ussize="13" data-persmaxchars="0" data-persmaxnums="0" data-perscanhaveflag="" data-status="" data-msg1="Available for Immediate Dispatch. " data-msg2="" value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

therefore to get a list of EU sizes you would need:

`//*[@id="size"]/option/@data-eusize`

Comment: wow that was very helpful !
and another thing ! i want to specify OUT OF STOCK products too , how could i do that ?

Comment: its the value of the " Data-status= "

Comment: Could you please answer ?

Comment: SO is not a we-write-your-solution-for-you service. Please do your own research and show what you learned and got so far. If you are stuck then ask a question with a specific issue you are having. see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In your case I suggest you read-up on xpaths & at least attempt to solve your own problem: [W3 schools Xpath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) - follow through by clicking the "next chapter" links near the top